# navigation bar with wrapper issue

Tags: css, wrapper, navigationbar

My entire theme for my site has a wrapper on it and it is cutting my navigation bar short about 20px on both the left and right side of the web page. Does anyone have any ideas about how to get the navigation bar on top of the wrapper so that it will not be cut short?

Is there a way to make the navigation bar encompass the entirety of the website horizontally without having to remove it and everything else from the wrapper?

Comment: Can you post some of your code, or better yet a jsfiddle with it?  There are ways to make it be on top... you could float it outside of the layout flow, you could use absolute or fixed positioning, etc, it just depends how the rest of the page is styled.

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:absolute` or a `float` will take the element out of the document flow.  This means that it can be treated like it's outside the wrapper without changing the actual structure of your HTMl.

Without showing an example of your code it's difficult to be any more specific, but playing with the positioning should fix it for you.